# How to increase my container width to accomodate more items

Tags: plotly-dash, dash-bootstrap-components

I am building a dashboard using Plotly Dash. I am using bootstrap.min.css , I would like to increase the width of my container so that I can accommodate two graphs , in a single row.

My second graphs(Line graph) , has more width hence unable to align them in a single row.

I have attached the snapshot below,
[image]

DASH UI CODE :

```
# the style arguments for the sidebar. We use position:fixed and a fixed width
SIDEBAR_STYLE = {

    "top": 0,
    "left": 0,
    "bottom": 0,
    "width": "16rem",
    "padding": "2rem 1rem",
    "background-color": "#f8f9fa",
    "position": "fixed",
    "color":"#000",
}

# the styles for the main content position it to the right of the sidebar and
# add some padding.
CONTENT_STYLE = {
    "margin-left": "18rem",
    "margin-right": "2rem",
    "padding": "2rem 1rem",

}

sidebar = html.Div(
    [
        html.H2("Plate", className="display-4"),
        html.Hr(),
        html.P(
            "A simple dashboard", className="lead"
        ),
        dbc.Nav(
            [
                dbc.NavLink("Dashboard", href="/dashboard", id="page-1-link"),
                dbc.NavLink("Analytics", href="/page-2", id="page-2-link"),
                dbc.NavLink("Page 3", href="/page-3", id="page-3-link"),
                html.Hr(),
                dbc.NavLink("Logout", href="/logout", id="page-4-link"),
            ],
            vertical=True,
            pills=True,
        ),
    ],
    style=SIDEBAR_STYLE,
)

content = html.Div(id='page-content' , className ='container' ,style=CONTENT_STYLE)



app.layout = html.Div([dcc.Location(id="url"), sidebar, content])
app.config.suppress_callback_exceptions = True


# this callback uses the current pathname to set the active state of the
# corresponding nav link to true, allowing users to tell see page they are on
@app.callback(
    [Output(f"page-{i}-link", "active") for i in range(1, 4)],
    [Input("url", "pathname")],
)
def toggle_active_links(pathname):
    if pathname == "/" or pathname == "/dashboard":
        # Treat page 1 as the homepage / index
        return True, False, False
    return [pathname == f"/page-{i}" for i in range(1, 4)]


@app.callback(Output("page-content", "children"), [Input("url", "pathname")])
def render_page_content(pathname):
    if pathname in ["/", "/page-1", "/dashboard"]:
        dashBoard = html.Div([
            html.Div([dcc.DatePickerRange(
                id='my-date-picker-range',
                min_date_allowed=dt(minDate[0],minDate[1],minDate[2]),
                max_date_allowed=dt(maxDate[0],maxDate[1],maxDate[2]),
                initial_visible_month=dt(maxDate[0],maxDate[1],maxDate[2]),
                start_date=dt(minDate[0],minDate[1],minDate[2]).date(),
                end_date=dt(maxDate[0],maxDate[1],maxDate[2]).date()
                ),
            html.Button(id="date-button" , children ="Analyze" , n_clicks = 0, className = 'btn btn-outline-success')
                ], className = 'row'),

            html.Div([
                html.Br(),      

                html.Div([

                    html.H4(['Category Overview'] , className = 'display-4'),
                    html.Br(),
                    html.Br(),
                    ], className = 'row'),
                html.Div([
                    html.Div([dcc.Graph(id='categoryPerformance',figure = dict(data=ge.returnCategoryOverviewBarGraph(df)[0],
                     layout=ge.returnCategoryOverviewBarGraph(df)[1]))

                        ], className = 'col'),
                    html.Div([dcc.Graph(id='categoryPerformanceTrend')

                        ], className = 'col')


                    ], className = 'row'),
                html.Hr(),
                html.Div([
                    html.Div([
                        dcc.Dropdown(id = 'category-dd', options = category_items, value = 'Food')

                        ], className = 'col-6 col-md-4'),
                    html.Div([

                        dcc.Slider(id = 'headCount' , min = 5, max=20 , step = 5 , value = 5, marks = {i: 'Count {}'.format(i) for i in range(5,21,5)})

                        ], className = 'col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-8')
                    ], className = 'row'),
                html.Div([
                    html.Br(),
                    html.Br(),
                    html.Div([

                        dcc.Graph(id ='idvlCategoryPerformanceBest')


                        ], className ='col'),
                    html.Div([

                        dcc.Graph(id ='idvlCategoryPerformanceLeast')


                        ], className = 'col')



                    ], className = 'row')




                ])



            ] , className='container')
        return dashBoard
```

I have zero knowledge in frontend / css , any help is much appreciated. Thanks !

Comment: Please provide some code that shows the structure of your Dash app.

Comment: @MrLeeh , I have updated my question with the UI code as well.

Comment: When it comes to Styling I'd suggest to checkout [Dash-Bootstrap](https://dash-bootstrap-components.opensource.faculty.ai/)

Comment: I think lots of folks would like to help you. Would be nice if you would make it easier to them by applying at least some proper formatting to your code.

Comment: In my editor its formatted, but while copy pasting here, it somehow become totally unformatted. Sorry

Comment: @Rudertier I have used Dash-Bootstrap, I have cloned the simple sidebar example.